# Stream socket with SSL

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, smtp

I have a problem with stream socket and SSL in PHP 5.6.
It seems that SSL is buffering output.
In the example below "ehlo" command is ignored (server is not responding).
But when something else is sent after "ehlo" e.g. a new line in another call to `fwrite`, server sends response.

```
$errno = '';
$errstr = '';
$timeout = 5;
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
$host = 'ssl://smtp.some.server.com:465';
$stream = stream_socket_client($host, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
stream_set_blocking($stream, 1);
stream_set_timeout($stream, $timeout);
stream_set_write_buffer($stream, 0);

$fgets = fgets($stream);
print_r($fgets);

fwrite($stream, "ehlo [127.0.0.1]\r\n");

$response = '';
do {
    $line = fgets($stream);
    $response .= $line;
} while (null !== $line && false !== $line && ' ' != $line{3});

print_r($response);

fclose($stream);
```

I've got a response:

`220 epicserver.net.pl ESMTP IdeaSmtpServer v0.80.2 ready.`

(it's from first `print_r`).

But when after line: `fwrite($stream, "ehlo [127.0.0.1]\r\n");` I add additional socket write: `fwrite($stream, "\n");` output is ok:

```
220 epicserver.net.pl ESMTP IdeaSmtpServer v0.80.2 ready.
250-epicserver.net.pl Hello ip-166-242.pl [94.183.162.232], pleased to meet you
250-PIPELINING
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-SIZE
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250 HELP
```

I've tried using stunnel to check if it's a PHP SSL wrapper issue and when I change `$host` to `$host = 'localhost:110;'` (my stunnel configuration) everything works perfectly (without adding that special `fwrite` method).

Did anyone face that problem?

Comment: Does e.g. http://swiftmailer.org exhibit the same problem? If not, you _could_ compare that implementation with yours.

Comment: Yes, that test code is taken from the swiftmailer implementation.

Comment: So, if you use swiftmailer with ssl://smtp.some.server.com:465 it doesn't work because it's not completing the handshake?

Comment: Connection is established, I get ready prompt from server. I can see that commands are sent but server responds to second-to-last command (the last one seems to be buffered). And the exact same issue is in my example code (stream context buffer something?).

Comment: Does it complete handshake ? Or I think it has a delay between that you need notice about

Comment: @OnlyMAJ read my previous comment. Connection is established, and handshake is done.

Comment: You should try stream_get_line instead of fgets. Maybe the server drops te connection, but fgets would not let you know...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php

Comment: You're in blocking mode, so `$line = fgets($stream);` actually blocks until you break a loop. try to put print_r inside a do-while loop.

Comment: Try flushing after sending `ehlo`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php

Comment: Windows or POSIX?

Comment: Could you please verify whether it's actually a PHP issue? look at tcpdump/wireshark and determine whether the data of the expected length is actually submitted? (data lengths are not a secret with SSL)

Answer (score 1):

Replace 1st fgets with this code, to be sure fgets understand line termination correctly:

```
$fgets = '';
while (is_resource($stream) && !feof($stream)) {
  $fgets .= fgets($stream); 
}
```